# Select single value from same columns based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table and using oracle sql

```
table name : TestCaseStatus

TestName  Status   TimeStamp
ABC       Passed   11.10AM (Same Date)
ABC       Failed   11.00 AM 
ABC       Failed   10.50 AM
EFG       Passed   11.00AM
123       Failed    11.10 AM
123       Passed    11.00 AM
```

Result

```
TestName  Status
ABC       Passed_On_ReRun
123       Failed
EFG       Passed
```

Question : Need query to get it. I have Tried MAX but not working

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, e.g. a test never failed, a test only failed never passed, a test passed twice etc.

Comment: Are all rows from the same _date_?

Comment: Yes, its same day run

Comment: added more data and need a query

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may be different depending on the product.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are the only three conditions, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select testname,
       (case when max(timestamp) = max(case when status = 'Failed' then timestamp end)
             then 'Failed'
             when max(timestamp) = max(case when status = 'Passed' then timestamp end) and
                  sum(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Passed_On_Rerun'
             when max(timestamp) = max(case when status = 'Passed' then timestamp end)
             then 'Passed'
             else '???'
         end)
from TestCaseStatus tcs
group by testname;
```

In Oracle, you can simplify this to:

```
select testname,
       (case when max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by timestamp desc) = 'Passed' and
                  sum(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Passed_On_Rerun'
             else max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by timestamp desc)
         end)
from TestCaseStatus tcs
group by testname;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b32472cf1203c7f7c9cfe78d0f9e36c3) is a db<>fiddle.

The `keep` syntax is getting the last value for the status based on the timestamp.

Comment: Getting below error after else max( )   "ORA-12704: character set mismatch
12704. 00000 -  "character set mismatch""

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select 
    TestName,
    case 
        when Status = 'Passed' and failed_once = 1 
        then 'Passed_On_Rerun'
        else Status
    end Status
from (
    select
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by TestName order by Timestamp desc) rn,
        max(case when Status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by TestName) failed_once
    from TestCaseStatus t
) t
where rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce5864393dda42b31268b0d78cb734df)**:

```
TESTNAME | STATUS         
:------- | :--------------
123      | Failed         
ABC      | Passed_On_Rerun
EFG      | Passed
```

Comment: You should add GROUP BY TestName and change "then 'Passed_On_ReRun'

Comment: In fact this can't work like this, you can even remove rank over clause and remove where rn = 1 and just add group by t.TestName in your subquery

Comment: @Gosfly: yes there was a typo where I put `Passed` instead of `Passed_On_Rerun`, fixed, thanks. No `groupu by` needed, as I explained this relies on window functions, not on aggregation.

Comment: It's ok, you could also add "over(partition by TestName) failed_once" as you just did, without this update your subquery would have only returned one row ...

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve what you want with the following query :

```
SELECT T1.TestName, T1.Status 
FROM TestCaseStatus T1
WHERE T1.TimeStamp = 
     (SELECT MAX(T2.TimeStamp) FROM TestCaseStatus T2 WHERE T2.TestName = T1.TestName)
```

However, there is an issue with your sample data :

```
123       Failed    11.00 AM
123       Passed    11.00 AM
```

Same test is failed and passed for the same timestamp ?!

Edit : In order to achieve the 'Passed_On_ReRun' need, we could imagine a solution like this :

```
SELECT T1.TestName, IF(T1.count > 0 AND T1.Status = 'Passed', 'Passed_On_ReRun', T1.Status)
FROM 
    (SELECT T2.TestName
            , T2.Status
            , SUM(T2.Status = 'Failed') AS count
            , MAX(T2.TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp 
     FROM TestCaseStatus T2 
     GROUP BY T2.TestName) T1
```

Comment: Thanks Corrected the timestamp.. it was typo

Comment: If test passed on subsequent run, i want them to report as Passed On rerun

Comment: "If test passed on subsequent run, i want them to report as Passed On rerun" ?? @archanak Then how is this correct answer ?

Comment: That helped me to narrow down the results, yes still it needs tweaking.

Comment: Then you do not mark it as correct because people think it is over. You just give it a up vote. And you can not give an up vote because you do not have enough popularity points...

Comment: @archanak See my edit above for your "Passed_On_ReRun" need